# Is there documentation that describes what C function names "stand for" (not what they do--rather, what the abreviated name means)?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls, manpage

Sometimes I have a hard time deciphering what C function names stand for. For example: the function `sigprocmask` changes the set of blocked signals, but I have no clue what the abbreviation `procmask` means. The [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) describes the behavior of the function, but does not mention the abbreviation.

Another example is the  constant `SIGWINCH`. I understand it is a singal that a window sized has changed, but it would be handy to have that plainly stated "`SIGWINCH` = **Sig**nal **Win**dow **Ch**anged." ***Does anyone know of such a resource?*** I have looked at several, and they all described the behavior, but ignored abbrevations. Thanks!

Comment: `sigprocmask` — signal process mask, or signal mask for process. Then the questions are "do you know what a signal is, and what a process is, and what the signal mask for a process is?"  The name section of the manual page sometimes gives the meaning.  The set of names was developed by numerous people working over many years — extreme consistency is not to be expected.

Comment: These are not C names. They are not defined by the C standard, nor are they particular to C (they may be used in other languages). They are parts of sets of software, such as Unix or Windows subsystems. Learning about software from reference pages can be a nuisance, as you have seen, especially since the man pages throw everything together. A better way to learn is to find primers, tutorials, or textbook material covering the specific subsystems or other software. This depends on the particular routines; you need a different document for each subsystem, so no single general document exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember in my early days of learning C that knowing what the function abbreviation stand for helped me a lot. So this is an attempt to demystify the abbreviations.

This post focuses on the abbreviation, not on the meaning. Thus some important points need to be raised:

- some abbreviations do not make make sense just by themselves. Either because some words are implicit, or because the order of the letters is *weird* when  expanding the abbreviation. For instance `iswprint()` is an abbreviation for "is wide printable". The meaning is "wide character is a printing character"
- some abbreviation are misleading. E.g. the `FPE` in `SIGFPE` stands for "Floating Point Exception", but the category is for arithmetic exceptions. E.g. `qsort()` stands for "quick sort" but the standard doesn't require this algorithm and it is usually implemented as a polymorphic sort.

---

## Standard Library

Structure follows https://en.cppreference.com/w/c

### Type Support

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `size_t` | size type |
| `ptrdiff_t` | pointer difference type |
| `NULL` | null |
| `max_align_t` | maximum align type |
| `offsetof` | offset of |
| `alignas` | align as |
| `alignof` | align of |
| `noreturn` | no return |

### Program support utilities

#### Program termination

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `abort` | abort |
| `exit` | exit |
| `quick_exit` | quick exit |
| `_Exit` | exit |
| `atexit` | at exit |
| `at_quick_exit` | at quick exit |

#### Communicating with the environment

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `system` | system |
| `getenv` | get environment (variables) |
| `getenv_s` | get environment (variables) safe |

#### Signals

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `signal` | signal |
| `raise` | raise |
| `sig_atomic_t` | signal atomic type |
| `SIG_DFL` | signal default |
| `SIG_IGN` | signal ignore |
| `SIG_ERR` | signal error |

#### Signal Types

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `SIGTERM` | signal termination |
| `SIGSEGV` | signal segmentation violation |
| `SIGINT` | signal interrupt |
| `SIGILL` | signal illegal instruction |
| `SIGABRT` | signal abnormal termination |
| `SIGFPE` | signal floating point exception |

#### Non-local jumps

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `setjmp` | set jump |
| `longjmp` | long jump |

#### Types

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `jmp_buf` | jump buffer |

### Variadic function

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `va_start` | variable arguments start |
| `va_end` | variable arguments end |
| `va_copy` | variable arguments copy |
| `va_arg` | variable arguments' argument |
| `va_list` | variable arguments list |

### Memory management

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `malloc` | memory allocation |
| `calloc` | clean allocation |
| `aligned_alloc` | aligned allocation |
| `realloc` | reallocate |
| `free` | free |

### Date and time utilities

TODO

### String Library

#### Null-terminated byte strings

**Character classification**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `isalnum` | is alphanumeric |
| `isalpha` | is alphabetic |
| `islower` | is lowercase |
| `isupper` | is uppercase |
| `isdigit` | is digit |
| `isxdigit` | is hexadecimal digit |
| `iscntrl` | is control |
| `isgraph` | is graphic |
| `isspace` | is space |
| `isblank` | is blank |
| `isprint` | is printable |
| `ispunct` | is punctuation |

**Character manipulation**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `tolower` | to lowercase |
| `toupper` | to uppercase |

**Conversions to numeric formats**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `atof` | ASCII to floating-point |
| `atoi` | ASCII to `int` |
| `atol` | ASCII to `long` |
| `atoll` | ASCII to `long long` |
| `strtol` | string to `long` |
| `strtoll` | string to `long long` |
| `strtoul` | string to `unsigned long` |
| `strtoull` | string to `unsigned long long` |
| `strtof` | string to `float` |
| `strtod` | string to `double` |
| `strtold` | string to `long double` |
| `strtoimax` | string to `intmax_t` |
| `strtoumax` | string to `uintmax_t` |

**String manipulation**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `strcpy` | string copy |
| `strcpy_s` | string copy safe |
| `strncpy` | string *n* copy |
| `strncpy_s` | string *n* copy safe |
| `strcat` | string concatenation |
| `strcat_s` | string concatenation safe |
| `strncat` | string *n* concatenation |
| `strncat_s` | string *n* concatenation safe |
| `strxfrm` | string transformation |

**String examination**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `strlen` | string length |
| `strlen_s` | string length safe |
| `strcmp` | string comparison |
| `strncmp` | string *n* comparison |
| `strcoll` | string collation |
| `strchr` | string (find) character |
| `strrchr` | string reverse (find) character |
| `strspn` | string span |
| `strcspn` | string complementary span |
| `strpbrk` | string pointer break |
| `strstr` | string (find) string |
| `strtok` | string tokenization |
| `strtok_s` | string tokenization safe |

**Character array manipulation**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `memchr` | memory (search) character |
| `memcmp` | memory comparison |
| `memset` | memory set |
| `memset_s` | memory set safe |
| `memcpy` | memory copy |
| `memcpy_s` | memory copy safe |
| `memmove` | memory move |
| `memmove_s` | memory move safe |

**Miscellaneous**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `strerror` | string error |
| `strerror_s` | string error safe |
| `strerrorlen_s` | string error length safe |

#### Null-terminated multibyte strings

**Multibyte/wide character conversions**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `mblen` | multibyte length |
| `mbtowc` | multibyte to wide character |
| `wctomb` | wide character to multibyte |
| `wctomb_s` | wide character to multibyte safe |
| `mbstowcs` | multibyte string to wide character string |
| `mbstowcs_s` | multibyte string to wide character string safe |
| `wcstombs` | wide character string to multibyte string |
| `wcstombs_s` | wide character string to multibyte string safe |
| `mbsinit` | `mbstate_t` initialization |
| `btowc` | byte to wide character |
| `wctob` | wide character to byte |
| `mbrlen` | multibyte reentrant length |
| `mbrtowc` | multibyte reentrant to wide character |
| `wcrtomb` | wide character reentrant to multibyte |
| `wcrtomb_s` | wide character reentrant to multibyte safe |
| `mbsrtowcs` | multibyte string reentrant to wide character string |
| `mbsrtowcs_s` | multibyte string reentrant to wide character string safe |
| `wcsrtombs` | wide character string reentrant to multibyte string |
| `wcsrtombs_s` | wide character string reentrant to multibyte string safe |
| `mbrtoc16` | multibyte reentrant to `char16_t` |
| `c16rtomb` | `char16_t` reentrant to multibyte |
| `mbrtoc32` | multibyte reentrant to `char32_t` |
| `c32rtomb` | `char32_t` reentrant to multibyte |

**Types**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `mbstate_t` | multibyte state type |
| `char16_t` | character 16-bit type |
| `char32_t` | character 32-bit type |

#### **Null-terminated wide strings**

**Character classification**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `iswalnum` | is wide alphanumeric |
| `iswalpha` | is wide alphabetic |
| `iswlower` | is wide lowercase |
| `iswupper` | is wide uppercase |
| `iswdigit` | is wide digit |
| `iswxdigit` | is wide hexadecimal |
| `iswcntrl` | is wide control |
| `iswgraph` | is wide graphic |
| `iswspace` | is wide space |
| `iswblank` | is wide blank |
| `iswprint` | is wide printable |
| `iswpunct` | is wide punctuation |
| `iswctype` | is wide character type |
| `wctype` | wide character type |

**Character manipulation**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `towlower` | to wide lowercase |
| `towupper` | to wide uppercase |
| `towctrans` | to wide character transformation |
| `wctrans` | wide character transformation |

**Conversions to numeric formats**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `wcstol` | wide character string to `long` |
| `wcstoll` | wide character string to `long long` |
| `wcstoul` | wide character string to `unsigned long` |
| `wcstoull` | wide character string to `unsigned long long` |
| `wcstof` | wide character string to `float` |
| `wcstod` | wide character string to `double` |
| `wcstold` | wide character string to `long double` |
| `wcstoimax` | wide character string to `intmax_t` |
| `wcstoumax` | wide character string to `uintmax_t` |

**String manipulation**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `wcscpy` | wide character string copy |
| `wcscpy_s` | wide character string copy safe |
| `wcsncpy` | wide character string *n* copy |
| `wcsncpy_s` | wide character string *n* copy safe |
| `wcscat` | wide character string concatenation |
| `wcscat_s` | wide character string concatenation safe |
| `wcsncat` | wide character string *n* concatenation |
| `wcsncat_s` | wide character string *n* concatenation safe |
| `wcsxfrm` | wide character string transformation |

**String examination**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `wcslen` | wide character string length |
| `wcslen_s` | wide character string length safe |
| `wcscmp` | wide character string comparison |
| `wcsncmp` | wide character string *n* comparison |
| `wcscoll` | wide character string collation |
| `wcschr` | wide character string (find) character |
| `wcsrchr` | wide character string reverse (find) character |
| `wcsspn` | wide character string span |
| `wcscspn` | wide character string complementary span |
| `wcspbrk` | wide character string pointer break |
| `wcsstr` | wide character string (find) string |
| `wcstok` | wide character string tokenization |
| `wcstok_s` | wide character string tokenization safe |

**Wide character array manipulation**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `wmemchr` | wide memory (search) character |
| `wmemcmp` | wide memory comparison |
| `wmemset` | wide memory set |
| `wmemcpy` | wide memory copy |
| `wmemcpy_s` | wide memory copy safe |
| `wmemmove` | wide memory move |
| `wmemmove_s` | wide memory move safe |

**Types**

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `wchar_t` | wide character type |
| `wint_t` | wide integer type |
| `wctrans_t` | wide character transformation type |
| `wctype_t` | wide character type type |

### Algorithms

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `qsort` | quick sort |
| `qsort_s` | quick sort safe |
| `bsearch` | binary search |
| `bsearch_s` | binary search safe |

### Numerics

#### Mathematical functions

TODO

#### Floating-point environment

TODO

#### Pseudo-random number generation

TODO

#### Complex number arithmetic

TODO

#### Type-generic math

TODO

### Input/output support

TODO

### Localization support

TODO

### Atomic operations library

TODO

### Thread support library

TODO

## POSIX

TODO